# Java try/catch procedure in matrix

Tags: java

Have this java code and need to add a try/catch so an error is displayed when typing in a non numerical character.  Where do I add the try/catch procedure so the error is displayed:

```
package SumadeMatrices;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumadeMatrices {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Ingrese el Numero de Filas: ");
        int rows = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese el Numero de Columnas: ");
        int columns = s.nextInt();
        int[][] a = new int[rows][columns];
        int[][] b = new int[rows][columns];
        System.out.println("Ingrese la primera matriz");
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                a[i][j] = s.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Ingrese la segunda Matriz");
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                b[i][j] = s.nextInt();
            }
        }
        int[][] c = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("La suma de las dos matrices es:");
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                System.out.print(c[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indent your code to adding readability

Comment: I agree with @DavideLorenzoMARINO that in the future you should strive to post only well-formatted code, code that we can easily read and thus easily understand. Thankfully Luigi took the time to edit your code for you, but again you should be doing this yourself in future posts. As to your question, what happens to your code now if you try to enter invalid data into it when it's running? What exceptions get thrown and where are they thrown?

Comment: noted..but I am a beginner in this...

Comment: since its about the input - you need to look at the place the false input comes in - which would be your scanner.nextInt() method - since the exception is thrown there (likely InputMismatchException) I would start to add the try/catch around these statements and look further from this point

Comment: I improved my answer, may be it will interesting for you to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanner uses different methods for converting string token after read. When converting is not possible, method throws `InputMismatchException`.
So there is a way to implement input validation by catching this exception.
In your case it might be like this:

```
    try {
        a[i][j] = s.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
```

Methods throw exceptions to allow you handle them with some logic. In your case user inputs values from keyboard to console and you decide what to do if input is invalid. For example, you may just break all input procedure, or you may ask for re-input.

Furthermore, often there are another options to check something besides catching exceptions. In case of `Scanner` there are `hasNext()` set of methods like `hasNextInt()`, so you can check input for being `int` and if it's not, just skip it by call `scanner.next()`.

```
while(!scanner.hasNextInt()){
    scanner.next();
}
a[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
```

Also you may implement this logic as your own method to avoid code repeat.

```
int nextKeyboardInt(){
    while(!scanner.hasNextInt()){
        scanner.next();
    }
    return scanner.nextInt();
}
a[i][j] = nextKeyboardInt();
//another code//
int anotherInt = nextKeyboardInt();
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels improved

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible approaches:

- Handle each exception and asking for reinput the data.
- Check if an error is thrown and exit with a message.

In the first situation you need to add a try catch for each `scanner.nextInt`. In this case you need to reinput the data.

```
// For each readInt
boolean inputed = false;
int myVariable;
while (!inputed) 
    try {
        myVariable = scanner.nextInt();
        inputed = true;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("The last input is not a number. Reinput");
    }
}
```

In the second situation you need to add a try catch for the whole function

```
 try {
     ....
     // whole function code
 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("An error has occured. Restart");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner#nextInt()` will throw a `java.util.InputMismatchException` if the user enters a non-numerical character.  You just need to catch it when it happens and display your helpful error message.

```
int value;
try {
    value = scanner.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("You dun goofed!");
}
```

Here's a more sophisticated solution that will keep asking until the user gives a valid input.  Consider putting this into it's own method that you can call every time you need a new value.

```
int value;
boolean hasValue = false;
while (!hasValue) {
    try {
        value = scanner.nextInt();
        hasValue = true;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("You dun goofed!");
    }
}
```